# How to secure file uploading in java

Tags: java, javascript, struts, xss

I am developing an web application using java where user will upload a zip file. This file will contain css files, images, javascript files, flash files etc. The zip file will be uploaded in the webapp directory of tomcat. Purpose is that user will upload skin as zip file and my servlet will extract this to a location in the webapp.

My concern is how to handle security here. User may write xss attack code in js file or other file. All files are inside the zip file. I can check extensions or mime type of zip file. Apart from that what other actions I could take to prevent any kind of attack. Any kind of example, code snippet will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There's an inherent risk here that's hard to mitigate down to (what I consider) an acceptable level of risk when you're dealing with "unsecured" users, ie users from the great big wild beyond and not those who have administrative rights to put any type of file on the server. So many risks here.

Comment: Okay, so you want to check for attacks from a .js file and possible others? well my first question is why not try use a virus scanner that has the commandline abilities to scan files, thus you will scan each file as it gets uploaded, if a virus scanner is out of the question maybe look towards VirusTotal.com's online API scanner. however without a proper heuristics engine, new attacks can be written and will pass through just as easily

Comment: Are you sure you need them to be able to upload javascript and flash files? Can't you design some sort of config file format that they can upload, and which is consumed by your own code to provide whatever they need?

Comment: Actually my user here are not end user. This option is for web designer and he can upload only. But there is no login for her/him. If a flag is enabled in the server side then the upload UI will be visible. Mostly this will be used in the development mode not in production mode. Though I want to ensure some security as there is no login.

Comment: Quick and easiest way "_to ensure some security_" here would be implementing a login, and restricting that feature to identified authenticated user, as these seem to be well-known, being web designer(s?) involved in your development process. Why try to mitigate a high risk (associated with "anyone can upload"), when you can lower that risk to something acceptable (if something goes wrong, you know who's accountable)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not specify what you are going to do with the uploaded content, but if you want to run this on your site, then the answer is that you really don't want people to be able to upload their own JavaScript. Any foreign code running on your side could change anything and make your site behave in ways you cannot take responsibility for. Just read [the Wikipedia entry on clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) to be convinced.

Clean all HTML by removing `script` tags to prevent JavaScript execution, don't allow custom JavaScript and for all customization needs follow the suggestion by @greyfairer of using a config file with script checking.

Also make sure to put a limit to the size of uploaded files (see web server documentation) if you are concerned about what your users are going to do to your site.